# fake group and filtering dc.js

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter, reductio

I have had to create a cumulative sum group and a remove_zero group for my project.
The issue arises when I combine them and filters on another dimension. It looks like the filter is not taken into account in my cumulative sum fake group.

I have put everything into [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chapo/5u2gn9f8/).

When filtering on `age` by clicking on the barchart on top (only the 1w will do something), both line charts at the bottom should have the same date span if I understand correctly since they're using the same dimension. But that does not happen. The top one does not rescale at all while the bottom one does.

[image]

The only difference between the 2 line graphs (that I can see) is in the group definition :

- top one :`.group(remove_zero_values(cumulSumGroup(groups.date.TOTAL_PNL)))`
- bottom one :`.group(remove_zero_values(groups.date.TOTAL_DELTA))`

My question is : how do I make sure that the top line graph also filters on dates when I click on the top bar chart ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are combining cumulative sum with filtering zeros, you will want to filter the zeros first:

```
.group(cumulSumGroup(remove_zero_values(groups.date.TOTAL_PNL)))
```

Otherwise, each bin will inherit a value from the last one, and very few of them will remain zero.

[Fork of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/jgpqh63f/2/).

Comment: In theory it should be small enough to stay below my threshold of 1 though. I'm surprised the order matters.

Comment: Yeah, I was a little confused why it works, because in your case the zeros should be at the start. I didn't dig any further once I saw it working (displays only Sep 8 onward). In general, yes order absolutely does matter because a value will wipe out any zeros that come after.

Comment: yes I meant the order in my specific case. Will have to dig further as I don't like not understanding why stuff works or not :)